# Enum.filter not scalable?

Tags: elixir, scalability

I decode a CSV file (using https://hexdocs.pm/csv/), producing a stream, and I filter this stream with `Enum.filter`. My problem is that the processing time does not grow linearly with the size of the CSV file:

```
% wc -l long.csv 
10000 long.csv
% time mix run testcvs.exs long.csv  
mix run testcvs.exs long.csv  3.08s user 0.50s system 242% cpu 1.479 total

% wc -l verylong.csv
100000 verylong.csv
% time mix run testcvs.exs verylong.csv 
mix run testcvs.exs verylong.csv  98.08s user 3.24s system 117% cpu 1:25.93 total
```

It should take ten times more but it actually takes 57 times more. Definitely not scalable. Does it mean that `Enum.filter` does not use streaming but instead loads everything in memory? Is there a more scalable way to filter a stream?

The code:

```
Enum.at(System.argv(), 0)
|> File.stream!([:read], :line)
|> CSV.decode([separator: ?;])
|> Enum.filter(fn {:ok, line} -> Enum.at(line, 11) == "" end)
```

Comment: if you want to use streams, you have to use Stream module functions, https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#filter/2

Comment: Of course, it now works. I regard the question as solved. Daniel, if you prefer to make a answer, I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: Beware that `Stream` is lazily evaluated, so unless you did anything afterwards with that stream, then your whole code can be reduced to `File.touch!(hd(System.argv()))`

Comment: Hauleth, the real code does other things afterwards but I posted the minimum example reproducing the problem.

Comment: This article https://www.poeticoding.com/processing-large-csv-files-with-elixir-streams/ can surely help you out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it mean that Enum.filter does not use streaming but instead loads everything in memory?

Yes. As Daniel mentioned in the comments, for streams you should use [`Stream.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#filter/2).

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) for Enum:

> Note the functions in the [`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module are eager: they will
> traverse the enumerable as soon as they are invoked. This is particularly
> dangerous when working with infinite enumerables. In such cases, you should
> use the [`Stream`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html) module, which allows you to lazily express computations,
> without traversing collections, and work with possibly infinite collections.
> See the [`Stream`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html) module for examples and documentation.